# Can a Templated User Control be used for data entry?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I've found code examples that demonstrate templated user controls. They work fine for displaying data, but I can't get them to work for entering data. I have a TextBox in my template, and can change the value in it, but I can't get that changed value in my code. I attempt to get the user control's values in a button click handler, but I always get just the initial value. Also, when I click the button, the templated user control's value(s) are reset. Is data entry supposed to work with templated user controls?

My code is similar to the MSDN topic "How to: Create Templated ASP.NET User Controls".

Default.aspx ===============================

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" tagname="TemplateTest" Src="TemplatedUC.ascx" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load()
    {
        DataBind();
    }

    protected void ButtonShowContent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ContentLabel.Text = string.Format("Index: {0} - Message: {1}<br>", TemplateTest1.Index, TemplateTest1.Message);
    }
</script>

<head runat="server">
    <title>Templated User Control Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Testing Templated User Control</h1>
<form id="Form2" runat="server">
    <uc:TemplateTest ID="TemplateTest1" runat="server">
      <MessageTemplate>
        Index: <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text='<%# Container.Index %>' /><br />
        Message: <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Label2" Text='<%# Container.Message %>' /><br />
      </MessageTemplate>
    </uc:TemplateTest>
    <asp:Button ID="ButtonShowContent" runat="server" Text="Show Content" onclick="ButtonShowContent_Click"  />
    <asp:Label ID="ContentLabel" runat="server" Text="&nbsp;" Width="100%" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

TemplatedUC.ascx ============================

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" ClassName="TemplatedUC" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.ComponentModel"  %>

<script runat="server">
private ITemplate messageTemplate = null;
private MessageContainer container = new MessageContainer(1, "Initial Text");

[ TemplateContainer(typeof(MessageContainer)) ]
[ PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty) ]
public ITemplate MessageTemplate {
    get 
    { 
        return messageTemplate; 
    }
    set 
    { 
        messageTemplate = value; 
    }
}
public int Index
{
    get { return container.Index; }
    set { container.Index = value; }
}
public string Message
{
    get { return container.Message; }
    set { container.Message = value; }
}

void Page_Init() {
    if (messageTemplate != null) {
            messageTemplate.InstantiateIn(container);
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(container);
    }
}

public class MessageContainer: Control, INamingContainer {
    private int m_index;
    private String m_message;

    internal MessageContainer(int index, String message)
    { 
        m_index = index;
        m_message = message;
    }

    public int Index {
        get { return m_index; }
        set { m_index = value; }
    }
    public String Message 
    { 
        get { return m_message; }
        set { m_message = value; }
    }
}
</script>

<asp:Placeholder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder1" />
```

If you run this and change the value for 'Message', then when you click the button, the data will be displayed. Thank you.

Comment: Please show a small code example. Since this happens to you all the time, could you reproduce it with a brand-new page, showing just the one text box in the one template?

Comment: @JohnSanders Here is my example:

Comment: Sorry, I don't see your example.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I can't fit my code example in the comments. Is there a 'correct' way to do this? (post code examples)

Comment: Edit your question and add it to the bottom. Be sure to indent by 4 to make it show up as code.